# Inconsistency detected, Recycle view while performing both pull to refresh and scroll list

Tags: android, scroll, pagination, pull-to-refresh

In my application, I am using SwipeRefreshLayout for pull to refresh functionality.

My application has also pagination while scrolling.

While i am pull to refresh my screen at same time when i try to scroll the recycle list it giving me following error.

> Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder

I know, it happens due to still data is not loading and i am trying to scroll page so another page data also load, its conflict here.

If at the same time i am showing progress dialog then it works well, because while showing progress dialog, screen touch is disable to user not able to scroll the listing, but i am not able to show pull to fresh circle and progress dialog at a time, so, i am not showing progress dialog while pull to refresh, but issue happen while i am scrolling list.

What to do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever user use pull to reflesh, you should notify adapter after clearing list